# How to modify arrow function to work in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have learned that arrow functions do not work in IE11. So my code below is throwing a syntax error in IE11. However, I'm having difficulty modifying it to a normal function. Here's the problem line of code:

```
let selectors = [nextSlide, nextSlide - slick.slideCount, nextSlide + slick.slideCount].map( n => '[data-slick-index="${n}"]' ).join(', ');
```

I tried changing `n =>` to `function(n) {}` like below, but that's giving an error in all browsers.

```
let selectors = [nextSlide, nextSlide - slick.slideCount, nextSlide + slick.slideCount].map( function(n) { '[data-slick-index="${n}"]' } ).join(', ');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the full function if it's helpful to see what's going on:

```
$('.text-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  let selectors = [nextSlide, nextSlide - slick.slideCount, nextSlide + slick.slideCount].map( n => '[data-slick-index="${n}"]' ).join(', ');
  $('.shimmer2').removeClass('shimmer2');
  $(selectors).addClass('shimmer2');
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: You forgot the `return`.

Comment: https://death-to-ie11.com/

Comment: Thank you. I added a return, which did fix the error. But it stopped my removeClass and addClass functions below it from working.

Comment: Can't come fast enough, @mkaatman

Comment: returning after those two lines?

Comment: I wonder if your selectors aren't working because your math is wrong?  I would assume that `nextSlide - slick.slideCount` will be a negative number.  Is that correct?

Comment: @James, the selectors work in my original code. They just don't work when I switch the arrow function to a normal function, so I don't think the math is different. But I'm also a javascript amateur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> let selectors = [nextSlide, nextSlide - slick.slideCount, nextSlide + slick.slideCount].map( n => '[data-slick-index="${n}"]' ).join(', ');
> ```

Arrow functions without braces like the one above implicitly return the result of the expression/statement. For arrow functions with braces or non-arrow anonymous functions like you have here, you want to `return` something explicitly:

```js
let selectors = [nextSlide, nextSlide - slick.slideCount, nextSlide + slick.slideCount].map(function(n) {
    return '[data-slick-index="${n}"]';
}).join(', ');
```

Comment: You edited out a blockquote... I didn't "add" anything, that's not my code, I was showing the asker which part of their code was being talked about.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you'd added the `function(n)` but now realise you were quoting the second example the OP gave. I'd suggest adding an actual example to make this answer worthwhile in this case, as all it does it point out the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to match your code, and this does resolve the error. But it doesn't work with the rest of my code anymore. The remove/add class functions are no longer applying. Would this return the selectors differently than the arrow function?

Comment: Nothing obvious would change that I can see given the code you provided; `selectors` would still be a single string (a single CSS selector, with 3 parts separated by commas). Can you log your `$(selectors)` to make sure it's picking up the elements you expect? No need to modify your code necessarily; you can probably just debug it directly in browser devtools, maybe with a breakpoint or watch expression in the beforeChange handler.